# Как сложить определенные ключи в хэше?

Tags: ruby

```
[{"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.042283965144168}, {"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.140509738669785}, {"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.305163801196718}, {"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.945557313139568}]
```

есть массив с вложенными хэшами, нужно посчитать сумму  всех consumption, как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Лучше - с какой точки зрения? Какой-то вариант у вас уже есть?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.042283965144168}, {"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.140509738669785}, {"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.305163801196718}, {"mark"=>"Cherry", "model"=>"A5 2,0i", "year"=>2018, "consumption"=>8.945557313139568}]

arr.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).map{ |k, g| {k => g.map(&:last)} }.detect{|f| f["consumption"] }.values.flatten.sum
```

Смотрится некрасиво, но работает

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map{|h| h['consumption']}.sum
```